# What's a phrase for looking over your accounts?

Tags: phrase-requests, finance

I'm looking for a phrase that means "to look over your accounts," but I know that's not how it's said in English. The phrase banging around my head is "take account," as in "He took account of all of this year's financials." A more likely possibility is "take stock," but I'm looking for a phrase specifically having to do with finances or accounts. Is there such a phrase? I haven't been able to find anything on Google or here.

Comment: What do you mean by "look over"? Do you mean to *care for*, to *check*, or to *investigate*, or something else?

Comment: @Lawrence To check your accounts to make sure they all add up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider *reconciliation*:

> Reconciliation is an accounting process that uses two sets of records to ensure figures are correct and in agreement. It confirms whether the money leaving an account matches the amount that's been spent, ensuring the two are balanced at the end of the recording period. The purpose of reconciliation is to provide consistency and accuracy in financial accounts.
>   [- INVESTOPEDIA](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/reconciliation.asp)

It carries the notion that you're checking / looking over your accounts to see that everything 'adds up'.

*Reconciliation* is something done to *accounts*. If you're looking for something done to *financials*, consider *audit*:

> An audit is an objective examination and evaluation of the financial statements of an organization to make sure that the records are a fair and accurate representation of the transactions they claim to represent.
>   [- INVESTOPEDIA](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/audit.asp?ad=dirN&qo=investopediaSiteSearch&qsrc=0&o=40186)

So you can say that:

- he *reconciled* his accounts; or
- he had this year's financials *audited*.

Answer (score 1):

"Looking over your accounts" is a simple and perfectly comprehensible English phrase. You don't need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

will review be the word

https://afr.fo.uiowa.edu/policies-procedures-resources/monthly-review-transactions-and-accounts

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/review

appraised might do as well

- following your response - if you want more rigour 'inspect' ?

inspect

ɪnˈspɛkt/Submit

verb

look at (someone or something) closely, typically to assess their condition or to discover any shortcomings.

"they inspected the paintwork for cracks and flaws"

examine (someone or something) to ensure that they reach an official standard.
"customs officers came aboard to inspect our documents"

synonyms:   examine, check (over), scrutinize, vet, investigate, test, monitor, survey, study, go over, look over, look at, take a look at, pore over, view, scan, observe, explore, probe, subject to an examination, subject to an inspection, go over with a fine-tooth comb; assess, appraise, review; informalcheck out, give something the once-over, give something a going-over, give something a look-see

"the safety equipment is inspected by officials each year"

seem some nice words in that lot

Comment: Review is a bit too general, and appraise doesn't really seem to apply in this context.